# Boundedness Of Abundance Of Product Of $N$ Consecutive Integers

Tags: real-analysis, factoring, integers, products

Is the abundance of the product of 2 consecutive integers (pronic numbers) bounded? What about the abundance of the product of 3 consecutive integers? What about $n$ consecutive integers? I wrote the following little Python script along the following lines to try and understand it better for the case $n=3$ (and I can generalize it), but I know that this is not a substitute for a proof. I found an abundance of approximately 3.294 for $54\times 55\times 56$, but nothing higher.

```
import math 
import time

i=1

def abundance(n): 
    sum=0
    i=1

    while i<=(math.sqrt(n)): 
        if n%i==0: 
            if n/i==i: 
                sum=sum+i 
            else:
                sum=sum+i 
                sum=sum+(n/i) 
        i=i+1

    sum=sum-n 
    return sum/n

while True:
  print("Abundance of "+str(i)+", "+str(i+1)+", and "+str(i+2)+" is "+str(abundance(i*(i+1)*(i+2))))
  i+=1
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: For your example of $54\cdot 55\cdot 56=166320=2^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11$, I got an abundance of $\frac{714240}{166320}=\frac{992}{231}\approx 4.294$.

Comment: $n=2924$ seems to give the greatest abundance for $n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)$ of all $n$ up to $10000$.  Other values of $n$ that 'beat' $54$ include $208; 350;$ and $2574$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the abundance of a positive integer $n$, I understand you to mean $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function.

Since the abundance of single integers is unbounded, so is the abundance of products of two (or more) consecutive integers, because in general: $\frac{\sigma(mn)}{mn}\ge \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$

---

As pointed out by @Daniel Fischer (thank you!), OP is defining abundance where the sum of factors only includes proper factors (i.e., $n$ is excluded in the sum of factors of $n$).  I am using the sum of all factors, including $n$.  This means that my value of the abundance of an integer $n$ will always be exactly one greater than OP's value.  However, the unboundedness argument I give is still valid.

Comment: The code says the OP calls $\frac{\sigma(n) - n}{n} = \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} - 1$ the abundance of $n$. Doesn't make a difference for the argument of course.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Fischer.  that explains why my result for $54\cdot 55\cdot 56$ disagreed with OP by $1$.

Comment: I understand how your result follows from $\frac{\sigma(mn)}{mn}\ge \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$, but I don't understand how you arrived at that inequality in the first place. Is that a well-known fact, or is the proof trivial?

Comment: @Lieutenant Zipp: It is fairly well known (and not difficult to show) that for any integer $n$, $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \sum_ {d\mid n} \frac{1}{d}$.  Since all the factors of $n$ are also factors of $mn$, the result follows.